# UNION ALL in Multiple Tables

Tags: php, mysql, postgresql, join, union-all

I need to UNION ALL multiple tables. I create a query via PHP and runs successfully without UNION ALL tables. But when I UNION ALL 2 tables, it seems that query never ends in php page also I tested in pgAdmin with the same result. I generated a CSV file as a result via shell obtaining the data I wanted to select but the query never ends too. I will appreciated your comments. Thanks in advance.

This is the query that UNION ALL multiple tables. The amount of tables that can be UNION ALL depends of a DateRangePicker. So there is a table per day, for example: F_UCell_1_170123, F_UCell_1_170124, F_UCell_1_170125, F_UCell_1_170126, etc...

```
SELECT 
to_date(T1.day::text,'YYYYMMDD'), 
T1.hour, 
cellname, 
Item67204837, Item73393830, ... , (199 columns listed in 7 tables listed below)

FROM ( 

SELECT 
day, 
hour, 
Cellkey, 
Item67204837, Item67199736 
FROM omstar_1486079935913_xsau.F_UCell_1_170123 

UNION ALL 

SELECT 
day, 
hour, 
Cellkey, 
Item67204837, Item67199736 
FROM omstar_1486079935913_xsau.F_UCell_1_170124) 

AS T1 

INNER JOIN ( 

SELECT 
day, 
hour, 
Cellkey, 
Item67183903, Item67180586, Item67183900, Item67180589, Item67180588, Item67180590, Item67183901, Item67180587, Item67183913, Item67183912, Item67180585 
FROM omstar_1486079935913_xsau.F_UCell_2_170123 

UNION ALL 
SELECT 
day, 
hour, 
Cellkey, 
Item67183903, Item67180586, Item67183900, Item67180589, Item67180588, Item67180590, Item67183901, Item67180587, Item67183913, Item67183912, Item67180585 
FROM omstar_1486079935913_xsau.F_UCell_2_170124) 

AS T2 ON 
T1.day = T2.day AND 
T1.hour = T2.hour AND 
T1.Cellkey = T2.Cellkey 

INNER JOIN (

SELECT 
day, 
hour, 
Cellkey, 
Item73394021, Item67190477, Item73394022, Item67189750, Item67190411, Item67189749, Item73425007, Item67189756, Item67189757, Item73425013, Item73394018, Item67193405, Item67189754, Item67190476, Item67192661, Item67193406, Item67192660, Item73425009, Item67189755, Item73426857, Item67190412, Item73425012, Item73426856, Item73425008, Item73423107 
FROM omstar_1486079935913_xsau.F_UCell_3_170123 

UNION ALL 
SELECT day, hour, Cellkey, Item73394021, Item67190477, Item73394022, Item67189750, Item67190411, Item67189749, Item73425007, Item67189756, Item67189757, Item73425013, Item73394018, Item67193405, Item67189754, Item67190476, Item67192661, Item67193406, Item67192660, Item73425009, Item67189755, Item73426857, Item67190412, Item73425012, Item73426856, Item73425008, Item73423107 
FROM omstar_1486079935913_xsau.F_UCell_3_170124) 

AS T3 ON 
T1.day = T3.day AND 
T1.hour = T3.hour AND 
T1.Cellkey = T3.Cellkey 

INNER JOIN ( 

SELECT day, hour, Cellkey, Item67193538, Item67190406, Item67193542, Item67179830, Item67192612, Item67193613, Item67190506, Item67179858, Item67193611, Item73403809, Item73424888, Item67179825, Item67193543, Item67189494, Item67189496, Item67193539, Item67193540, Item67180083, Item67180081, Item67190457, Item73424884, Item67190840, Item73393835, Item67180078, Item67189568, Item67179967, Item73393837, Item67180077, Item67180079, Item67193537, Item67190505, Item67189557, Item73424885, Item67180067, Item73426209, Item73394298, Item73423519, Item67190461, Item67192613, Item67180082, Item67179777, Item67190409, Item67203416, Item67179780, Item67180074, Item67180069, Item67179930, Item67189572, Item67180076, Item67190841, Item67190408, Item73424887, Item67193541, Item73393836, Item67193612, Item73424889, Item67180080, Item67192610, Item67192611, Item67193614, Item67190407, Item67179827, Item73424886, Item67180068, Item67193536, Item67179864, Item67179922, Item67179925, Item67179778, Item67179926, Item67179781, Item67179927, Item67179826, Item67179921, Item67179928, Item67179924, Item67179828, Item67179923, Item67179779, 
FROM omstar_1486079935913_xsau.F_UCell_4_170123 

UNION ALL 

SELECT day, hour, Cellkey, Item67193538, Item67190406, Item67193542, Item67179830, Item67192612, Item67193613, Item67190506, Item67179858, Item67193611, Item73403809, Item73424888, Item67179825, Item67193543, Item67189494, Item67189496, Item67193539, Item67193540, Item67180083, Item67180081, Item67190457, Item73424884, Item67190840, Item73393835, Item67180078, Item67189568, Item67179967, Item73393837, Item67180077, Item67180079, Item67193537, Item67190505, Item67189557, Item73424885, Item67180067, Item73426209, Item73394298, Item73423519, Item67190461, Item67192613, Item67180082, Item67179777, Item67190409, Item67203416, Item67179780, Item67180074, Item67180069, Item67179930, Item67189572, Item67180076, Item67190841, Item67190408, Item73424887, Item67193541, Item73393836, Item67193612, Item73424889, Item67180080, Item67192610, Item67192611, Item67193614, Item67190407, Item67179827, Item73424886, Item67180068, Item67193536, Item67179864, Item67179922, Item67179925, Item67179778, Item67179926, Item67179781, Item67179927, Item67179826, Item67179921, Item67179928, Item67179924, Item67179828, Item67179923, Item67179779, Item67179782 
FROM omstar_1486079935913_xsau.F_UCell_4_170124) 

AS T4 ON 
T1.day = T4.day AND 
T1.hour = T4.hour AND 
T1.Cellkey = T4.Cellkey 

INNER JOIN ( 

SELECT 
day, 
hour, 
Cellkey, 
Item67199780, Item73423508, Item67190405, Item73423488, Item73423498, Item67179331, Item67199680, Item67199619, Item67179527, Item67179462, Item73423506, Item67190586, Item67204827, Item73423510, Item67192609, Item67190401, Item67179465, Item67180641, Item67179459, Item67179336, Item67179464, Item73423490, Item67193609, Item73423502, Item73410511, Item67179338, Item73423486, Item67190404, Item67179457, Item67193610, Item67179299, Item73423504, Item67199625, Item67199623, Item67179332, Item67199556, Item73423494, Item67199621, Item73423496, Item67199624, Item67179466, Item67179460, Item67180642, Item67190621, Item67179329, Item67199620, Item73423492, Item67204826, Item67179337, Item67199682, Item73425032, Item67179334, Item67199622, Item67180648, Item67192608, Item67179525, Item73410510, Item67179524 
FROM omstar_1486079935913_xsau.F_UCell_5_170123 

UNION ALL 

SELECT 
day, 
hour, 
Cellkey, 
Item67199780, Item73423508, Item67190405, Item73423488, Item73423498, Item67179331, Item67199680, Item67199619, Item67179527, Item67179462, Item73423506, Item67190586, Item67204827, Item73423510, Item67192609, Item67190401, Item67179465, Item67180641, Item67179459, Item67179336, Item67179464, Item73423490, Item67193609, Item73423502, Item73410511, Item67179338, Item73423486, Item67190404, Item67179457, Item67193610, Item67179299, Item73423504, Item67199625, Item67199623, Item67179332, Item67199556, Item73423494, Item67199621, Item73423496, Item67199624, Item67179466, Item67179460, Item67180642, Item67190621, Item67179329, Item67199620, Item73423492, Item67204826, Item67179337, Item67199682, Item73425032, Item67179334, Item67199622, Item67180648, Item67192608, Item67179525, Item73410510, Item67179524 
FROM omstar_1486079935913_xsau.F_UCell_5_170124) 

AS T5 ON 
T1.day = T5.day AND 
T1.hour = T5.hour AND 
T1.Cellkey = T5.Cellkey 

INNER JOIN ( 

SELECT 
day, 
hour, 
Cellkey, 
Item67180483, Item67180498, Item67180508, Item67192689, Item67180484, Item67180491, Item67180490, Item67180509, Item67180499 
FROM omstar_1486079935913_xsau.F_UCell_6_170123 

UNION ALL 

SELECT 
day, 
hour, 
Cellkey, 
Item67180483, Item67180498, Item67180508, Item67192689, Item67180484, Item67180491, Item67180490, Item67180509, Item67180499 
FROM omstar_1486079935913_xsau.F_UCell_6_170124)

AS T6 ON 
T1.day = T6.day AND
T1.hour = T6.hour AND 
T1.Cellkey = T6.Cellkey 

INNER JOIN ( 

SELECT 
day, 
hour, 
Cellkey, 
Item67189840, Item67192114, Item67203850, Item67192486, Item67190567, Item67192115, Item67192487, Item67190704, Item73403763, Item73393832, Item73403761, Item67190705, Item67202932, Item73393830 
FROM omstar_1486079935913_xsau.F_UCell_8_170123 

UNION ALL 

SELECT 
day, 
hour, 
Cellkey, 
Item67189840, Item67192114, Item67203850, Item67192486, Item67190567, Item67192115, Item67192487, Item67190704, Item73403763, Item73393832, Item73403761, Item67190705, Item67202932, Item73393830 
FROM omstar_1486079935913_xsau.F_UCell_8_170124) 

AS T7 ON 
T1.day = T7.day AND 
T1.hour = T7.hour AND 
T1.Cellkey = T7.Cellkey 

INNER JOIN 

omstar_1486079935913_xsau.d_ucell as Tn on T1.cellkey = Tn.cellkey 

WHERE Cellname IN ('U06CZPA' ) ORDER BY T1.day, T1.hour;
```

The columns are distributed in F_UCell_1 or F_UCell_2 or ...  or F_UCell_6 or F_UCell_8. **It is missing F_UCell_7** (Total 7 tables that are JOIN by `INNER JOIN`)

Comment: All ItemXXXXXXXX fields are the ones I wanted to select in first SELECT. They are distributed in tables F_UCell to complete the 203 columns to be selected.

Comment: You have no pair for `Item67179782` in your example. If it is the same in your query then you'll have an error because `UNION` requires to have the same number of columns in both united tables. 'it seems that query never ends in php page' - probably your php code can clarify the problem.

Comment: The PHP file prints the query I pasted,  all the columns match for every UNION ALL and there are not error. When the line pg_query is executed in php, it nevera ends to continue they code... I dont have PHP file available. I will paste asap

Comment: you should consider a diffrent data structure! Idea: design your Tables as Types: `create type F_UCell (day int, hour int, Cellkey int, Items int[]);` and make a table of those Cells.

Comment: @Beaver So have you tried your query against simple tables of the same structure? If you are sure you have no errors in SQL and PHP then it has sense to make mocks of each table in your query (with the same structure but with just few rows, for example 3-5 in each) and try your query against them. It will help you to understand if you are dealing with a performance problem or not.

Answer (score 0):

@alex_edev, Im testing right now and it works fine with just one column, so it is a performance issue. Also I have differents servers (1 for web page and other one for DB server) in the same LAN. The result for all columns is about 150 mb, so it could be a network issue. 
@Ben H, the design of the table was previous designed an have already data, so re-design the table is not a option.